# GL_STEREO not supported! but it should... (Use Nvidia 3D Vision from Psychopy (or Matlab))

Tags: opengl, nvidia, stereo-3d, psychopy

I would like to use the Nvidia LCD shutter glasses (3D Vision 2) with Psychopy to present different images to left and right eye.
The glasses work perfectly when used with the Nvidia demos and test, but not when used via Psychopy.
My computer is equipped with a Quadro K4000 and relative stereo bridge with 3-pin connector, latest driver (361.91), 3D-ready monitor, Windows 7 64bit.

I am aware you need to properly enable the stereo mode from the Nvidia control panel and I did this. Specifically:

- Stereo - Enable to On;
- Stereo - Display Mode to Generic active stereo (with Nvidia 3D Vision), and also tried On-board DIN connector (with Nvidia 3D Vision).

From Psychopy, when trying to display stimuli stereoscopically using following code

```
    win = visual.Window(...., stereo=True)
    while True:
    #clear may not actually be needed
    win.setBuffer('left', clear=True)
    #do drawing for left eye
    win.setBuffer('right', clear=True)
    #do drawing for right eye
    win.flip()
```

I get the this warning:

```
WARNING A stereo window was requested but the graphics card does not appear to support GL_STEREO".
```

Despite this, the stimuli are stereoscopically displayed but with excessive cross-talk.

Actually I also tried to use the Nvidia 3D Vision with Matlab and the Psychophysics Toolbox, but again with no success.

I would be very grateful for any help!
Thanks

Alex

EDIT:
From the warning I get in PsychoPy it really seems that GL_STEREO is not supported, because gl_info.have_extension('GL_STEREO') does return False for some reason...
How come that extension is missing if I have a Quadro K4000 with latest driver and enabling stereo mode from control panel??

Comment: Which version of OPENGL is isntalled?

Comment: It is OpenGL 4.5, which comes along with the graphics driver 361.91.

Comment: Sorry, I need to rectify. The version of OpenGL installed is 4.4. I verified this by using an OpenGL viewer.